# Custom Sort options for Catalog Dropdown

Tags: filter, sortby

I created:
di.xml on app/code/Filter/Sorting/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Filter_Sorting::addCustomSortOptions" type="Filter\Sorting\Plugin\Model\Config" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Filter_Sorting::implementCustomSortOptions" type="Filter\Sorting\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>
```

for my Config.php on app/code/Filter/Sorting/Plugin:

```
<?php
namespace Filter\Sorting\Plugin\Model;
 
class Config
{    
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        //Remove default sorting options
        unset($options['position']);
        unset($options['name']);
        unset($options['price']);
 
        //New sorting options
        $options['newest'] = __('New product');        
        $options['name'] = __('Name');        
        $options['price_desc'] = __('Price High to Low');
        $options['price_asc'] = __('Price Low to High');
        $options['name_asc'] = __('Title: A-Z');
        $options['name_desc'] = __('Title: Z-Z');
        $options['release_date'] = __('Release Date');
        $options['sales_popularity'] = __('Bestselling');
        $options['rating_summary'] = __('Top Rated');
        $options['reviews_count'] = __('Most Reviewed');
 
        return $options;
    }
}
```

and file Toolbar.php on app/code/Filter/Sorting/Product/ProductList:

```
<?php
namespace Filter\Sorting\Plugin\Product\ProductList;
 
class Toolbar
{    
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $currentOrder = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder();
        $currentDirection = $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
        $result = $proceed($collection);
 
        if ($currentOrder) {
            switch ($currentOrder) {
 
            case 'newest':
                if ($currentDirection == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('e.created_at ASC');
                } elseif ($currentDirection == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('e.created_at DESC');
                }
            break;
 
                      
 
            case 'name':
                if ($currentDirection == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('name ASC');
                } elseif ($currentDirection == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('name DESC');
                }
            break;
 
            case 'price_desc':            
                if ($currentDirection == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('price ASC');
                } elseif ($currentDirection == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('price DESC');
                }
            break;
 
            case 'price_asc':
                if ($currentDirection == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('price DESC');
                } elseif ($currentDirection == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('price ASC');
                }
            break;   

            case 'name_desc':
                if ($currentDirection == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('name DESC');
                } elseif ($currentDirection == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('name ASC');
                }
            break;  

            case 'name_asc':
                if ($currentDirection == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('name ASC');
                } elseif ($currentDirection == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('name DESC');
                }
            break; 

            case 'sales_popularity':
                $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('sales_popularity', 'desc');
                break;

            case 'rating_summary':
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                $this->_collection->getSelect()->join('review_entity_summary',
                    'review_entity_summary.entity_pk_value=e.entity_id and review_entity_summary.store_id=' . $storeId,
                    ['rating' => 'ceiling(rating_summary/10)', 'reviews_count'])->order(['rating desc', 'reviews_count desc']);
                $this->_collection->setOrder('rating_summary', 'desc');
                break;

            case 'reviews_count':
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                $this->_collection->getSelect()->join('review_entity_summary',
                    'review_entity_summary.entity_pk_value=e.entity_id and review_entity_summary.store_id=' . $storeId,
                    ['rating_summary', 'reviews_count'])->order(['reviews_count desc']);
                $this->_collection->setOrder('reviews_count', 'desc');
                break;


 
            default:        
                $this->_collection
                    ->setOrder($currentOrder, $currentDirection);
            break;
 
            }
        }        
        //var_dump($currentDirection);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

But latest switch case: rating_summary and reviews_count - not working, where i wrong? Thanks.

Comment: $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); this is M1 code. You need to used M2 structure code.

Comment: Can you tell me how better?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get store id, then use into your code.

```
public $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    ...        
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;        
    ...
}

public function execute()
{
   /* Get Current Store ID */
   $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
```